# Cannot install nvidia driver for ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, cuda

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 (64 bit) with kernel version is 3.16.0-40-generic. And my nvidia is

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 650M] [10de:0fd1] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device [144d:c0d1]
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
Memory at f6000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
I/O ports at e000 [size=128]
Expansion ROM at f7000000 [disabled] [size=512K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

That mean it is GeForce GT 650M. Hence, I went to [nvidia search](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx) to check which nvidia is good for my laptop. I found version 346.72. However, when I install it. I cannot log-in my computer. It allway repeat log-in screen when I login. I need to uninstall it. Then it can log-in again. What is my problem? How to resolve it?
I also tried do with other method such as

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa -y
$ sudo apt-get update
# install the latest version
$ sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

But it shown that (Note that I install 304 version before but I uninstall it)

```
nvidia-current is already the newest version.
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cuda-drivers : Depends: nvidia-340 (>= 340.29) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: nvidia-340-dev (>= 340.29) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: nvidia-modprobe (>= 340.29) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libcuda1-340 (>= 340.29) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: nvidia-libopencl1-340 (>= 340.29) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: nvidia-opencl-icd-340 (>= 340.29) but it is not going to be installed
 nvidia-340-uvm : Depends: nvidia-340 (>= 340.29) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Update error: When i tried to uninstall current nvidia and install new nvidia 331 version it shown as

```
 Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.19.0-20-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia-331/331.113/build/make.log for more information.

Setting up nvidia-331-uvm (331.113-0ubuntu1~xedgers14.04.1) ...
Loading new nvidia-331-uvm-331.113 DKMS files...
First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building only for 3.19.0-20-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 3.19.0-20-generic
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.19.0-20-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia-331-uvm/331.113/build/make.log for more information.
Setting up nvidia-opencl-icd-331 (331.113-0ubuntu1~xedgers14.04.1) ...
Setting up nvidia-prime (0.6.2) ...
nvidia-prime start/running, process 13152
Setting up nvidia-settings (352.09-0ubuntu0~xedgers14.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.6) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
```

After remove all nvidia, I typing sudo ubuntu-drivers devices it shown

```
~# sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00000FD1sv0000144Dsd0000C0D1bc03sc00i00
model    : GK107M [GeForce GT 650M]
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
driver   : nvidia-349 - third-party free
driver   : nvidia-352 - third-party free recommended
driver   : nvidia-331 - third-party free
driver   : nvidia-340 - third-party free
driver   : nvidia-346 - third-party free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
driver   : nvidia-331-updates - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-304-updates - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-304 - third-party free
```

After reinstall ubuntu, I based on the suggest of Plo.. I think I install successfull by checking

```
$lspci -knn | egrep 'VGA|3D' -A2 
or Graphics Controller [8086:0166] (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device [144d:c0d1]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 650M] [10de:0fd1] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device [144d:c0d1]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

Comment: Try to remove all nvidia drivers, boot with 3.16 kernel using grub menu and install nvidia-331.

Comment: How to remove 316 kernel  by terminal? And version of nvidia is 331 or 346? Thanks

Comment: You do not need to remove kernel. You can boot to any installed kernel using grub menu. So boot with 3.16 and install 331 driver, that is default in ubuntu. Check if it works. What is grub menu and how to get there you can find by using search.

Comment: Of course, I choose newest kernel. I removed all nvidia kernel by your command. But when I typing sudo ubuntu-drivers devices it show as in updated question. That mean it does not remove succesfull, Right?

Comment: My command does not remove kernel. It removes driver. It seems that you do not understand my posts. Do you see difference between kernel and driver? If not, I suggest re-installing the system from scratch and trying to install default nvidia-331 and do not touch kernel at all.

Comment: Sorry. It is driver. I missing typing

Comment: Sir, could you tell me version 331 or 346 is good for me?

Comment: The one that works is good for you. Both work for ME. Does any work for you?

Comment: Thank. I reinstall ubuntu and it work now. When I check, nvidia 331 is installed. How to know it is install successful?

Comment: Run `lspci -knn | grep VGA -A2`, if it shows "Kernel driver in use: nvidia", then it is OK.

Comment: Good job. It show as Kernel driver in use: i915
Thanks so much

Comment: i915 is for Intel. Post full output of `lspci -knn | egrep 'VGA|3D' -A2`

Comment: Now it looks good

Comment: Thanks for your help. I cannot upvote your answer because I have no score

Comment: Please do not add [solved] to question titles. I removed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all I suggest removing all nvidia drivers.

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
```

For Ubuntu 14.04 the default and preferred driver is nvidia-331.

It can be installed by

```
 sudo apt-get install nvidia-331
```

As an option you can upgrade kernel and install newer drivers.

Upgrade kernel to 3.19

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid
```

reboot

Then install nvidia-346 from xorg-edgers

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-346 nvidia-prime nvidia-settings
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
```

Look for errors when install. In most cases the driver works well, but it depends on graphical stack version installed, your integrated adapter model, etc.

If the driver does not work and graphics does not start, press Ctrl+Alt+F1, login to console and run

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
```

Comment: Thank Pilot6. I tried with first command to remove nvidia in Ctrl+Alt+F1 but it shown as link https://www.dropbox.com/s/o07xy9isag8w56k/log?dl=0

Comment: So run `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: Thanks. I followed your steps by step but when I login, the screen is black. I must goto Ctrl+Alt+F1 to remove all drive and it can login again. I upgrade my linux kernel to 3.19

Comment: Well. I do not have a ready solution. Hybrid graphics are not supported well enough. I am sure it can be fixed. But in this format it is hard to debug. I suggest asking at ubuntuforums.org

Comment: Thanks. It is my result when I call sudo apt-get install nvidia-current https://www.dropbox.com/s/a8yu6hiwewcp5qr/error.txt?dl=0

Comment: Do not install nvidia-current. It is for old adapters. You can install either a default nvidia-331, or nvidia-346 from the ppa.

Comment: Yes. I just debug. Because when I install newest version of nvidia. I cannot login. However, when i type ...nvidia-current. It install 304 version and i can login. I upgrade my linux version to 3.19.0-20-generic

Comment: Try to remove nvidia-current and install nvidia-331.